# CAS Delegated Authentication with ADFS

Tags: java, spring, authentication, cas, adfs

I'm trying to setup CAS with delegated authentication with ADFS. I checked the documentation for [delegation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/integration/Delegate-Authentication.html) and for adding [ADFS integration](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/integration/ADFS-Integration.html).
When I try to run the CAS server, I get the exception below. Can someone help me understand what is going wrong?

```
2018-07-20 18:01:15,247 WARN [com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.MetricsConfigurerAdapter] - <Problem stopping reporter>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'casMetricsConfiguration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

I'm using this CAS version:

```
   __   ____      _      ____   __  
  / /  / ___|    / \    / ___|  \ \ 
 | |  | |       / _ \   \___ \   | |
 | |  | |___   / ___ \   ___) |  | |
 | |   \____| /_/   \_\ |____/   | |
  \_\                           /_/ 

CAS Version: 5.2.5
CAS Commit Id: 6bbfdac91a20be3ace0d90de3ed837ada5b60438
CAS Build Date/Time: 2018-06-25T11:24:41Z
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.12.RELEASE
------------------------------------------------------------
Java Home: /Users/bart/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u152-zulu/jre
Java Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
Java Version: 1.8.0_152
JVM Free Memory: 372 MB
JVM Maximum Memory: 3 GB
JVM Total Memory: 586 MB
JCE Installed: No
------------------------------------------------------------
OS Architecture: x86_64
OS Name: Mac OS X
OS Version: 10.13.6
OS Date/Time: 2018-07-20T18:01:10.183
OS Temp Directory: /var/folders/rw/ps9zf0vn7vn92rfslbzl4nzm0000gn/T/
------------------------------------------------------------
Apache Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.30
------------------------------------------------------------
```

This my pom.xml. I added 'cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow' and 'cas-server-support-wsfederation-webflow'. The dependencies for 'fasterxml', 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect' and 'javax.servlet-api' were added becauses of earlier build issues. I'm not sure if this is correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verifyDownload>true</verifyDownload>
                    <checksumAlgorithm>MD5</checksumAlgorithm>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <executable>${isExecutable}</executable>
                    <layout>WAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                    <archive>
                        <compress>false</compress>
                        <manifestFile>${manifestFileToUse}</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cas</finalName>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <cas.version>5.2.5</cas.version>
        <springboot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <app.server>-tomcat</app.server>

        <mainClassName>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClassName>
        <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
        <manifestFileToUse>${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp${app.server}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFileToUse>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-pac4j-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-wsfederation-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth-releases</id>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>default</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!--
                ...Additional dependencies may be placed here...
                -->
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>exec</id>
            <properties>
                <mainClassName>org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication</mainClassName>
                <isExecutable>true</isExecutable>
                <manifestFileToUse></manifestFileToUse>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>echo</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <echos>
                                <echo>Executable profile to make the generated CAS web application executable.</echo>
                            </echos>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>bootiful</id>
            <properties>
                <app.server>-tomcat</app.server>
                <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>pgp</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.s4u.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pgpverify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <pgpKeyServer>hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net</pgpKeyServer>
                            <pgpKeysCachePath>${settings.localRepository}/pgpkeys-cache</pgpKeysCachePath>
                            <scope>test</scope>
                            <verifyPomFiles>true</verifyPomFiles>
                            <failNoSignature>false</failNoSignature>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving dependencies to the default profile, where it says:

```
<!--
...Additional dependencies may be placed here...
-->
```

And i reduced the depencies to the 2 I actualy need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verifyDownload>true</verifyDownload>
                    <checksumAlgorithm>MD5</checksumAlgorithm>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <executable>${isExecutable}</executable>
                    <layout>WAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <recompressZippedFiles>false</recompressZippedFiles>
                    <archive>
                        <compress>false</compress>
                        <manifestFile>${manifestFileToUse}</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cas</finalName>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <cas.version>5.2.5</cas.version>
        <springboot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <app.server>-tomcat</app.server>

        <mainClassName>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClassName>
        <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
        <manifestFileToUse>${project.build.directory}/war/work/org.apereo.cas/cas-server-webapp${app.server}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFileToUse>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>shibboleth-releases</id>
            <url>https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>default</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cas-server-support-wsfederation-webflow</artifactId>
                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>exec</id>
            <properties>
                <mainClassName>org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication</mainClassName>
                <isExecutable>true</isExecutable>
                <manifestFileToUse></manifestFileToUse>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>echo</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <echos>
                                <echo>Executable profile to make the generated CAS web application executable.</echo>
                            </echos>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>bootiful</id>
            <properties>
                <app.server>-tomcat</app.server>
                <isExecutable>false</isExecutable>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apereo.cas</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cas-server-webapp${app.server}</artifactId>
                    <version>${cas.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <id>pgp</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.s4u.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pgpverify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>check</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <pgpKeyServer>hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net</pgpKeyServer>
                            <pgpKeysCachePath>${settings.localRepository}/pgpkeys-cache</pgpKeysCachePath>
                            <scope>test</scope>
                            <verifyPomFiles>true</verifyPomFiles>
                            <failNoSignature>false</failNoSignature>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Now my CAS servers runs and I can configure the ADFS integration settings.